# how to install the Intel 82845G Graphics controller Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, video, intel-graphics

in the page :

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Desktop+graphics+drivers&ProductProduct=Intel%c2%ae+82845G+Graphics+Controller

format files are rpm and gz they are not designed for ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install anything. The drivers for intel graphics cards are open source and already integrated into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The 82845g doesn't seem to work well in any Linux distro. It randomly freezes. Switching to the vesa driver will prevent this, but only allow a very low resolution display.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this thread is pretty old, but I found some information that may help any future visitors who come here as I did in a desperate search for answers. I have a circa-2004 Dell Dimension 2400 with the 82845G chipset that I really wanted to install Linux on for a client, and was about to give up - esp. after reading numerous posts like this - when I decided to give Lubuntu 14.04 a try. Much to my amazement it installed and ran fine with all updates installed. Its not the perfect DE for this particular client (I was hoping for something a little more Windows-like, as they are Linux virgins) but hey, it works! Hope this info helps someone else as well